# Anylogin key requirement error in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

[image: Error message]

I have the kind of error in above image when I login with anylogin gem. But login works fine when I log in with my default email and password. I am also using devise gem in my app.
Couldn't find the solution in internet.

Answer (score 0):

In URL in screenshot you used params "locale", but your required params is "locales".

Comment: oh thats true. Thanks for the help @Hanna Kalesnikava